# Is it possible to download using a google API the pages that are "Crawled - currently not indexed"?

Tags: java, google-api

In the google search console in the "Page indexing
-> Crawled - currently not indexed" section there is a list of URL that are affected. I can download the urls in question from the interface.

Is there a way to download the above list of URLs using a google API?

Regards
Conteh

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into this website? This can be helpful.

https://www.upbuild.io/blog/download-linked-from-urls/

(Sorry for asking as an answer I don't have reputation to comment.)